# How do I remove unwanted launch configurations from the run/debug menu?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Why does the drop-down menu for choosing Run/Debug configurations show a spurious item, and how can I get rid of it?

In the Run/Debug configuration drop-down menu it shows five items in total:

1. test_city
2. launch Edge on port 5001
3. launch Edge on port 5000
4. Node.js ...
5. Add configuration ...

The first two are what I defined in launch.json. The last two are standard. But item 3 is a mystery -- its name is something that I used to have in launch.json but have since deleted. When I try to run it, I get the error message `Configuration 'Launch Edge port 5000' is missing in 'launch.json'`.

Why does vscode show it to me, if it doesn't have a definition in launch.json? How can I get rid of it?

**Update:** If I click on the launch text on the status bar at the bottom of VScode, it shows a dropdown asking me to choose a launch configuration. It lists items 1 and 2 as "launch.json", then items 3 and 4 as "contributed", then item 4 as "configure". So, who is contributing them? Did my Javascript plugin somehow decide to contribute item 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the drop down had an extra 2 configurations, I believe both were created from the `Add Configuration...' shortcut option in the dropdown. These configs don't appear to be stored anywhere like normal launch configs.

Deleting this folder fixed my issue:

`~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage`

To find this, I copied my `Code` folder, closed VSCode, deleted a random folder, opened VSCode, and repeated until the extra configs went away. Then I compared the two folders using FileMerge, excluding identical, and noticed the workspace folder containing a sqlite db `Code/User/workspaceStore/{workspaceId}/state.vscdb`. I'm not sure what in that db causes the extra launch configs, but it seems that's where the setting is stored.

You can explore the table like this:

```
$ sqlite3 state.vscdb
sqlite> .tables
ItemTable
sqlite> .mode table
sqlite> select * from ItemTable;
```

Comment: The key is `debug.recentdynamicconfigurations`. Delete it using `delete from ItemTable where key = 'debug.recentdynamicconfigurations';`

Comment: The file `workspace.json` records the folder location of workspace. You can use text search to find the right workspace ID.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this issue about duplicates but the temp fix might work for you:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/121148#issuecomment-828458208

Try the temporary fix provided there to clear local storage:

> Delete the local storage. This will loose some UI state but nothing
> too drastic. Here's the location's

Windows: `C:\Users\<userid>\AppData\Roaming\Code\Local Storage`
Linux: `/home/<userid>/.config/Code/Local Storage`
macOS: `/Users/<userid>/Library/Application Support/Code/Local Storage`

Comment: I deleted my Windows local storage, but it didn't help. (I'm running VSCode in Windows, connecting to a WSL2 setup, in case that makes any difference.)

Comment: This didn't do anything for me